# Rebus and distributed workers

Tags: nservicebus, worker-process, rebus

We are currently evaluating Rebus and NServiceBus.
Does Rebus have anything similiar to NServiceBus's distributed workloader yet?
Its a bit hard to discern from the docs :).

Kind regards
Christian

Comment: Since you are evaluating why not have a look at my FOSS project: http://shuttle.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately Rebus does not have a distributor yet - for the single reason that I've not yet experienced that the performance has been a problem.

On my (VMWare-based) Windows machine I can send ~700 msg/sec and receive ~3500 msg/sec with Rebus.

What are your performance requirements?

If you do require massive message processing capacity, you can use Rebus with RabbitMQ. With RabbitMQ, there's no need for a distributor since RabbitMQ works very well in a [competing consumers](http://www.eaipatterns.com/CompetingConsumers.html) setup.

Comment: We are in the process of preparing an old system to handle a lot more customers and have a lot of batch services in which we could use a bus to distribute work and avoid doing a lot of threading or rewritting (thight schedule as always :)). I have never looked into RabbitMQ as I had heard some bad things about it but if it supports competing consumers out of the box i will give at a look right away :). To bad theres no support for competing consumers in msmq :).

Comment: Thx for the talk a CNUG last year by the way :).

Comment: Awesome! Please don't hesitate to contact me if you encounter any difficulties :)

Comment: One also needs to take into account the performance of the business logic (and the DB it's talking to) - raw service bus performance isn't representative.

Comment: I could not find anything documenting that RabbitMQ supports MSDTC, so that was a deal breaker :/. We have started running some initial tests with the NSB Distributor instead.